# In the following line of code what does "android","theme","@style"and "AppTheme" represent

Tags: android, android-resources

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I think "android" represents a function or a class?
What is "theme" called technically?
"@style" is the string and it's  value being "AppTheme", I presume?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this "code" is a XML attribute, and defines the visual style of your EG `Activity`.

- `android` being a XML name space alias, usually used by Android XML schemas.
- `theme` is the name of the attribute, that is defined in the name space declared previously as `android`.
- `@style` is a reference to a group of "resources", in this case to predefined styles.
- `AppTheme` is a predefined Style for the entire app.

See also @cricket_007 's link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml